# Reading 2 million record from text file and add them to arraylist

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data from big text file and add them in Array list but it give me the following error:-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

My Code:

```
List<Book> books= new ArrayList<>();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String fileRead = null;
    Book book = null;
    while((fileRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(fileRead.startsWith("#index")) {
            book = new Book();
            book.index = fileRead.substring(6); 
            books.add(book);
        }
```

Comment: can you try reading with nio package?

Comment: Do you have any link to guide me how to use nio package in my code ?

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-nio-read-file-example/

Comment: If you know a good estimate for the *max* number of records in the given text file, you can pass that as a constructor argument to the ArrayList constructor. This will ensure it's allocated with enough space to hold them in, so that it doesn't have to do excessive reallocation and shifting so many times.

Comment: @gparyani I tried that but it didn't work ,it took much time and never terminated

Comment: This may help: [you need to allow your JVM more Java heap space to run properly](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

This is because reserved memory for JVM cannot keep that much of memory objects. Depending on your RAM, you may be trying to do impossible operation. Amount of your free RAM decides how much of Book Objects you can hold in memory. Try adding memory limits and run from command line.

`java -Xmx2000m -Xms2000m ....`

Comment: It took much time and never terminated